# Selecting the top three columns for each row and saving the results along with index in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, numpy, dataframe

I am using the below code to iterate through rows of a dataframe

[image: df]

Here is the sample dataset :

```
device_id   s2  s41 s47 s14 s24 s36 s4  s23 s10
3           0   0   0   0.002507676 0   0   0   0   0
5           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
23          0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
42          0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
61          0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
49          0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   7.564063476
54          0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.001098988 0
```

and sort the top 3 values from each row.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    row_sorted = row.sort_values(ascending=False)
    print (index,row_sorted)
```

here is a sample output

```
123 s16    1.054018
    s17    0.000000
    s26    0.000000
```

I have also tried with the below code:

```
top_n = 3
    pd.DataFrame({n: df.T[col].nlargest(top_n).index.tolist() 
                  for n, col in enumerate(df.T)}).T
```

to do it all at once but here is the output :

`49  s16   s1  s37` -- 49 is the row number here.

As you can see the outputs do not match and the first output is the correct one.

What I am looking for is a final dictionary which contains the index as key and the top 3 columns as values:

```
{123 : 's16','s17','s26'}
```

These will be used further down the line to iterate through another dictionary to_map which has the following structure:
`ID": ["s26", "International", "E", "B_TV"]` from where I will select "E" and "B_TV"

Comment: please provide a small reproducible data set as CSV/JSON/dictionary in __text__ format, so it could be used (copy & paste) for coding.

Comment: @MaxU.. Added please

Comment: could you also add your desired data set based on that sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this vectorized approach:

Sample DF:

```
In [80]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,7)), columns=['id']+list('abcdef'))
    ...: df = df.set_index('id')
    ...:

In [81]: df
Out[81]:
    a  b  c  d  e  f
id
4   4  0  8  8  4  8
0   2  4  7  3  1  4
9   3  6  5  7  3  4
5   7  6  3  8  9  1
6   3  7  6  1  7  9
```

Solution:

```
In [82]: idx = np.argsort(df.values, axis=1)[:, ::-1][:, :3]

In [83]: pd.DataFrame(np.take(df.columns, idx), index=df.index).T.to_dict('l')
Out[83]:
{0: ['c', 'f', 'b'],
 4: ['f', 'd', 'c'],
 5: ['e', 'd', 'a'],
 6: ['f', 'e', 'b'],
 9: ['d', 'b', 'c']}
```

PS replace `[:, :3]` with `[:, :top_n]`